# Why is link_to in Rails not invoking javascripts for the linked page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a link_to on my page and when I click on it, it takes me to the correct page, but no javascript gets executed. When I refresh the page, it works fine. How do I fix this so that link_to actually makes a new request to the server?

Thanks

Comment: Disable turbolinks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your link remote so it executes your ajax request.

An example of it would be as follows:

```
<%= link_to my_path, method: :post, :remote => true do %>
  <i class="icon-update"></i>
<% end %>
```

Please post more information about your code in case this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: I used this:
`<%= link_to construction_site.project, construction_site_path(construction_site), method: :post, :remote => true  %>`
but it doesn't work, it doesn't link at all, it just gives me this:
`<a rel="nofollow" href="/construction_sites/15/show" data-remote="true" data-method="post"`

I know that #show is a get method, so I changed it, but still..

Comment: This tells me you're not actually calling it as an Ajax link. Can you send some of your code (updating the post) and give a bit more info?

Comment: Awesome @ivanacorovic! Do you wanna mark this as answered then?